# How to run an application on a specific Java version?

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu

How can I run an application with a specific Java version? I have three Java versions intstalled:

```
myuser@mysystem:~$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
There are 3 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      auto mode
* 1            /opt/jdk-9.0.4/bin/java                          1         manual mode
  2            /opt/jdk1.8.0_162/bin/java                       1         manual mode
  3            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      manual mode
```

I have Java 9 set as default and I'd like to keep it that way. Still, an application named `pdfsam` doesn't seem to work properly with Java 9. What command is necessary to run it with openjdk (option 3)?

Comment: What is the command you use to run your application?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can run `java` with the absolute path to the installation

This would be your default `/usr/bin/java` installation

```
java -version
```

To change it, use the absolute path

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -version
```

If you're not running the `java` command directly, try setting the JAVA_HOME variable:

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/" pdfsam
```

Answer (score 0):

As I needed a specific version of Java for a specific application (["Jitsi Desktop" no more supported](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1273190/how-to-install-jitsi-from-the-unstable-repo/1324208#1324208) and works with JDK 8). The only way to get this specific version is to download it, uncompress and make application use it. In my case the JAVA_HOME environment variable does not working since the JDK is not really installed in the system.

So I found this simple method : install the JDK version needed and execute the specific application with specifying which version of JDK using with temporarily modifying the PATH environment variable.

In my case (the **user** must have right to read and execute the JDK) :

```
user@host:~$ PATH=/data/noinstall/jdk8u332-b09/bin/:$PATH jitsi
```

Note : adapt the path of the JDK's bin directory before the colon

So PATH is modified only during the execution of **jitsi**. Elsewhere during the execution or after the execution, PATH stay unchanged.

As `update-alternatives --config java` change the JDK globally I suppose this solution makes more comfortable the use cases with many different versions of JDK installed on the same system, dev, etc.

Based on [this topic](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/699507/how-can-i-install-java-8-on-debian-11-bullseye/699509#699509) and my intuitions.